# Could locking an enumerable potentially cause multiple enumeration?

Tags: c#, resharper, ienumerable

I think ReSharper is lying to me.

I have this extension method that (hopefully) returns an xor of two enumerations:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Xor<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second)
{
    lock (first)
    {
        lock (second)
        {
            var firstAsList = first.ToList();
            var secondAsList = second.ToList();

            return firstAsList.Except(secondAsList).Union(secondAsList.Except(firstAsList));
        }
    }
}
```

ReSharper thinks I'm performing a multiple enumeration of an IEnumerable, as you can see, on both the arguments. If I remove the locks, then it's satisfied that I'm not.

[image: Multiple enumeration]

Is ReSharper right or wrong? I believe it's wrong.

---

*edit*: I do realize that I'm enumerating the lists multiple times, but ReSharper is saying I'm enumerating over *the original arguments* multiple times, which I don't think is true. I'm enumerating both arguments once into a list so I may then perform the actual set manipulation, but as I see it, I'm not actually iterating over the arguments passed multiple times.

For example, if the passed arguments are actually query results, my belief is this method won't cause a storm of queries to be executed by the set manipulation. I do understand what ReSharper means by warning of multiple enumeration: if the enumerables passed are heavy to generate, then if they're enumerated multiple times, then performing multiple enumerations on them will be much slower.

Also, removing the locks definitely makes ReSharper happier:

[image: No multiple enumeration]

Comment: One thing to consider is that wrapping a block of code in a try/finally block (which is what lock is syntactic sugar for) makes the code within the block *less* optimizable.  Without the try/finally there may be something there that can be optimized or that R# recognizes as optimizable and thus doesn't complain.  I would suggest comparing the two blocks of code w.r.t. the generated IL.  I would also suggest you narrow the question down to what AakashM detailed--you *are* enumerating twice in your example, provide an example that has the warning but isn't enumerating twice.

Answer (score 2):

You are indeed enumerating both of the lists multiple times.  You are not enumerating the enumerables passed as parameters multiple times.  Both lists are enumerated once for each call to `Except`.  The call to `Union` is not enumerating either sequence an additional time, but rather is enumerating the results of the two calls to `Except`.

Of course, iterating a `List` multiple times in a context like this isn't really a problem; there aren't negative consequences to iterating an unchanging list multiple times.

The `lock` statements have nothing whatsoever to do with enumeration of the sequences.  Locking on an `IEnumerable` does not iterate it.  Of course, locking on two objects like this, specifically two objects that are not limited in scope to this section of code, is *very* dangerous.  It's quite possible to end up deadlocking the program with locks used in this manor if code elsewhere (such as another invocation of this method) ends up taking locks on the same objects in the opposite order).

Comment: I just updated my original question; removing the locks does make ReSharper think the issue is fixed.

Comment: @user3466413 My answer still answers your question, even after the edits.

Comment: How would you advise making this threadsafe if locking the arguments is the incorrect approach? My goal is to ensure that the enumerations aren't modified in the middle of the call to `Xor<T>` by another thread.

Comment: @user3466413 It shouldn't be the responsibility of this method to handle such a situation.  The calling code should be written such that it doesn't call this method on sequences being accessed from other threads.

Comment: @user3466413 "Locking" an object does not make it immutable. Other method could still modify the contents of the locked object while its locked.

Comment: Servy, I hate to disagree with you, but it's not the multiple enumeration of the **lists** that R# is complaining about; it's (what it perceives as) multiple enumerations of the **`IEnumerable` arguments**. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25994875) for my take. Do you know of any *guarantees* about what `Monitor.Enter` will do to its argument?

Comment: @AakashM I address both sets of sequences in this answer, not just one or the other.  And yes, we know that `Monitor.Enter` won't actually call `GetEnumerator` on the `Enumerable`.  How could it?  For it to use that method it would mean that only objects having such a method could be passed into `Monitor.Enter`.  All it will do is access the objects metadata, not call its methods.

Comment: Question is about why *just* adding the locks makes R# complain.

Comment: @PeterRitchie Because R# presumably considers any use of the variable will enumerate it, even if it won't.  Determining conclusively if any use of the variable will result in its enumeration is almost certainly impossible.  It can only flag *potential* cases of multiple enumeration given the information available to it.  In this case, you know more than it does.  R# could potentially cover this special case, but there will always be special cases it can't cover.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a funny one.

First things first: as you've correctly identified, R# is raising this inspection **not** against the multiple usages of the *`List`s* - there is of course nothing to worry about in multiply enumerating a `List` - but against (what R' sees as multiple usages of) the *`IEnumerable` arguments*. I'm presuming you already know why this would be potentially bad, so I'll skip that.

---

Now to the question of whether R# is right to complain here. To quote the C# spec,

> A lock statement of the form
>
> ```
> lock (x) ...
> ```
>
> where `x` is an expression of a reference-type, is **precisely
>   equivalent** to
>
> ```
> System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(x);
> try {
>   ...
> }
> finally {
>   System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(x);
> }
> ```
>
> except that `x` is only evaluated once.

(I've put in this emphasis because I like this wording; it avoids debates (that I'm definitely not qualified to enter) about whether this is "syntatic sugar" or not.)

Taking a minimal example which produces this R# inspection:

```
private static void Method(IEnumerable<int> enumerable)
{
    lock (enumerable)
    {
        var list = enumerable.ToList();
    }
}
```

and replacing it by what I think is the **precisely equivalent** version as mandated by the spec:

```
private static void Method(IEnumerable<int> enumerable)
{
    var x = enumerable;
    System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(x);
    try
    {
        var list = enumerable.ToList();
    }
    finally
    {
        System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(x);
    }
}
```

**also** produces the inspection.

The question then is: is R# **right** to produce this inspection? And this is where I think we get into a grey area. When I pass the following enumerable to either of these methods:

```
static IEnumerable<int> MyEnumerable()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enumerable enumerated");
    yield return 1;
    yield return 2;
}
```

it is **not** multiply enumerated, which would suggest that R# is wrong to warn here; however, I can't actually find anything in documentation that **guarantees** this behaviour of either `lock` or `Monitor.Enter`. So for me it's not quite as clear-cut as [this R# bug I reported, where use of `GetType` flagged this inspection](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-288467); but nonetheless I'd guess you're safe.

If you raise this [on the R# bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RSRP), you can get JetBrains' finest looking at a) whether this behaviour is indeed guaranteed. and b) whether R# can be adjusted to either not warn, or provide a justification for warning.

---

That said, of course, using locking here probably isn't actually achieving what you want to achieve, as stated in other answers and comments...